# Save file with custom extension using CreateChooser on Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have to ask the user to choose a location and save the file with a custom extension (.tdr). I have set intent.SetType to */* and currently I have to save file without any extension. Can anyone please help me to resolve my issue?

Here is my code sample

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetType("*/*");
                intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, false);
                intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
                MainActivity.Instance.persistentStorageService.Write("DataToWrite", projectJson);
                MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Save TRW Project File"), RequestCodeConstants.FilePickerSaveRequestCode);
```

In MainActivity.cs

```
System.IO.Stream output = ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(data.Data);
                            var dataToWrite = persistentStorageService.Read("DataToWrite", typeof(string));
                            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((string)dataToWrite);
                            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            output.Close();
                            result = buffer;
```

I want to save file in custom extension.

Comment: what kind of data is stored in your file?

Comment: @FreakyAli file contains a long JSON string

Comment: So you always have to create a new file with "x" name and ".tdr" extension right?

Comment: @FreakyAli correct.

Comment: @FreakyAli we can pass an extension with ExtraTitle but the user can remove it while giving the file a name. It would be nicer if there was a way like saving pdf with SetType("application/pdf")

Comment: Android just like iOS has made this a restriction now that If you have a file that you need to save in a User's device then they have the right to change the file name you won't be able to do anything on any file type... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your MimeType, it needs to be set to octet for custom file types:

```
intent.SetType("application/octet");
```

Once you do that all you need to do is StartActivityForResult and you are done.

```
Activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, resultCode);
```

Make sure your extension type is a part of the file name itself, you can assign that through intent as well

```
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, fileName);
```